Are there Bible translations that consistently include ALL meaning-altering Textus-Receptus variants in the footnotes?
Given that proponents of Textus Receptus Only are still influential today and that the majority of Bible translations today are using the Nestle-Aland edition, I wonder whether there are Bible translations that cater to both Greek editions by consistently providing the original Greek text as well as the translation of the variant not used in the main text.  CONSISTENTLY is the operative word here, so that Textus-Receptus only Bible readers can benefit from non-KJV translations to help them understand Scripture better (by using a modern translation) while trusting that the Textus Receptus manuscript version is always present to them.  It makes sense from the Marketing perspective.
Although of course one could consult Wikipedia or a list of differences in a web article, or use a tool such as BibleGateway to display it side by side, it is a lot more user-friendly to see the variant as a footnote that is available offline.  My preliminary research shows that alternate manuscript footnotes are sporadic, not consistent.  For example, for Matt 19:16-17 CSB only shows the mss variant in v. 17, but not in v. 16, and not show the Greek itself.  Bible Hub does have links to alternate manuscript but it's not indicated in the main text as an alert.
Given that such a dual-manuscript translation is not available easily today, what is the easiest way to read the Bible and be consistently alerted when a Textus-Receptus variant exists?  I know I can use tools like the Logos software to do side by side interlinear translations of both CSB and KJV/YLT, but it's not that easy to spot a variant.  So I will also accept an answer that can provide a recipe for using a software like this to read a Bible normally but has footnote, color codes, etc. to alert me that a meaning-altering Textus Receptus variant exists.

NOTE (after feedback in comments). Of course I wouldn't want any variants that don't make a difference in meaning. My Question has to do with making sure that the 3 text traditions (let's also add the Eastern Orthodox text tradition whose OT is based on Septuagint) are well represented in footnotes that should include a judgment from within each tradition on how that variant is likely.  Each translation based on a particular text tradition already winnowed out meaningless variants BY THAT tradition, so in my ideal Bible those variants don't need to be mentioned at all.
So I just want the 3 tradition text critic (TR, NA, and EO) to do their job well within their text-tradition, and the Bible publisher would present their 3 works in a single Bible volume with the main text coming from one of the 3 (the rest is in the footnotes).  So 3 Bible committees consulting their respective text-critic experts, and 1 publisher.

I simply cannot comprehend why a person who embraced the Textus Receptus and rejected the Westcott & Hort/Nestle Aland 'Critical Text' would wish to read a modern translation with footnotes telling them when a TR 'variant' (as you term it) is available. (If indeed that is what you are advocating, for your system here is quite confusing.) Those of us who follow John Burgon and Hermon Hoskier are quite content with KJV/YLT/EGNT. Why on earth would we alter that for something so cumbersome ? The modern versions with their 'dynamic equivalence' are more paraphrases than translations.

The next thing for publishers to foist on the bible-reading public will be the 'AI' version. I just can't wait.

@NigelJ My question has to do with non-English languages as well.  Are there Textus Receptus non-English translations out there?  Unlike you, I am personally not beholden to a text edition, so if the main text is Textus Receptus but has consistent Nestle-Aland text as footnotes, I would purchase it.  The scenario I proposed simply reflects the market reality today.  Similarly, if there are three text traditions represented (including the Septuagint), it's even better!  Yes, strict adherence to a text edition IS a tradition, but at heart I'm a Protestant.

@NigelJ About my ideal system, the Bible committee would start with their assessment of the best original language variant possible for each verse, some agree with TR, some with NA, some SG, etc.  All non-picked variants are in the footnotes. Then it's translated into the target language according to the translation philosophy; can be as literal as YLT, dynamic as NLT, or somewhere in between.  The key thing is that it's the Bible committee making the choice from all available 3 text traditions while showing the choices to the reader.  Isn't it a good combination of expertise and transparency?

You seem to want to embrace everything, inclusively. Which will merge all distinctions, hide that which would stand out as separate, and cover up all that should be revealed. This is a sign of the end times : the merging of everything into one, global 'utopia' under  one Rule and Authority. I don't need to guess at what Entity would be present, in spirit, in such a 'Bible Committee'.

for detailed differences in the bible, you will have to know Greek. I dont think there is an English version that would be so detailed as the Greek. How is the detail of NKJV footnotes?

@Michael16  Yesterday I answered this Q, which contains some info on the NKJV re. its footnotes and marginal readings. If you obtain the two TBS documents I reference, you will get a scholarly answer to the Q in your comment. https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/103613/why-was-the-byzantine-text-type-written

@NigelJ "You seem to want to embrace everything, inclusively. ...  one Rule and Authority. I don't need to guess at what Entity would be present, in spirit, in such a 'Bible Committee'"  In our decade today, there are so many options; no single Bible Committee can rule.  And if people remember that the Word is not the text, they wouldn't succumb to letting themselves be ruled by a Bible committee.  Your insisting on a doctrine that there is a single privileged text tradition, is actually one step closer to making that possible.

There are half a million Greek variations in/of the NT. The vast majority make no difference to the English meaning.  Daniel Wallace gives a lecture on this on YouTube where "John loves Mary" can be the translation from thousands of Greek sentences.  Not sure if anyone really wants all the Greek variants.. it would be a cumbersome, meaningless and useless addition.

If you mean variants that produce a meaningful variation in the English then, yes, that would be useful.  Is that what you are aiming for?
The rest of this I write partly from a YouTube video of a lecture by my current favorite textual critic, Daniel Wallace entitled "How badly was the New Testament corrupted?"
From 29 minutes into the video:
There are just over 138,000 words in the Greek New Testament, and 500,000 Greek textual variants.  I believe there are about 5,800 ancient Greek manuscripts producing these half a million variants.
This means there are (about) 3.5 textual variants for every word in the NT, or a verse of say 15 words would have over 50 textual variants.
At first sight this is a bit worrying.
Perhaps you should see the video to find out why it is not only not worrying, but actually good news.
But what it does mean is that it is entirely pointless, and impossibly cumbersome, to have all the Greek variants for the Textus Receptus.  If you mean you want all the variants for the few manuscripts which Erasmus et al worked, then the question would obviously be: Why do you want just these Greek manuscripts and not others?
But which textus receptus do you mean? The reason I ask can be seen from the wikipedia entry under "Textus Receptus".
John Mill (1645-1707) worked on 82 manuscripts and came up with about 30,000 variants in the Greek, in "Novum Testamentum Graecum".  Today, I believe we have 5,800 ancient Greek manuscripts, nearly all portions of the NT, mostly small portions.
It is really not possible or useful to produce a Bible with all the variants.  Most variants make no difference whatsoever to the English translation. Daniel Wallace in another youtube video shows there are thousands of ways to write the Greek for "John loves Mary": all are equally accurate in the Greek.
The somewhat alarming situation of the multiple variations of the Greek of the NT can be compared with the situation for the Qu'ran, which Moslems claim is so much better because they claim there is only one version of the Qu'ran in existence today. This claim is today being challenged as never before: see the work of Qu'ranic textual critic, Dan Brubaker, at www.danielbrubaker.com.
Let us suppose that in fact it is true, there is only one ancient Arabic version of the Qu'ran.  Does this prove that this ancient version is the original version?  Does it prove that Muslims, in this version, have the Word of (their) prophet, and (their) God?  Of course, it does not prove it at all.  It could be completely different from what was said by Mohammed and what was first written down by his followers.  It could also mean that an early Muslim sought out all the variations of the Qu'ran, produced a single version which attempted to harmonise all the variants, and then burned the variants:  but how would anyone know today that the harmonisation was a good one? We would not and could never know. (If you read (free, online) volume 6, book 61 of Hadith Bukhari (the most accepted authoritative Hadith of all) what I have just written is exactly what happened (Bukhari,vol 6,book 61, verse510). Khalifa Uthman ordered the burning. For him Unity amongst Muslims was more important than Truth.  Having unity was more important than having a clear knowledge of the words of their prophet, and presumably what God had said through him. (Nevertheless, there are multiple variations in the Qu'ran today as argued by Jay Adams.)
Now consider the case with the Bible and its half a million variant readings.  What we can FIRSTLY learn is there was no conspiracy or politically motivated attempt to produce a single version with no variants.  There were no bonfires of variant readings in the early church: praise God!  In the early Church there was no prioritising unity amongst Christians above the preservation of all variant readings, praise God: we have a rich tapestry of variant readings, from which textual critics can try to get us back to what is likely the original Word.  No one in the early church had sufficient political power to enforce any bonfires, or to try to enforce the suppression of variants, praise God.  (Nor, as far as we know, was there any desire or any arrogant claim to know which was the original.) The NT scriptures had spread out very quickly across many countries.  Suppression was not possible without political power, and there was no political power across so many countries.  Also there is no record of such suppression in the historical accounts: it simply does not exist, because it never happened, and we have 500,000 variant readings to prove it!
SECONDLY, for Christians Truth is important!  What God has said is more important than anything else.  It is more important than unity amongst Christians.
THIRDLY, the variants make no difference to any essential Christian doctrine: Bart Ehrman, the world's leading atheist Biblical textual critic, trained by Bruce Metzger, has said as much. From Christianapologetics.org

Interviewer: "Bruce Metzger, your mentor in textual criticism to whom this book is dedicated, has said that there is nothing in these variants of Scripture that challenges any essential Christian beliefs (e.g. the bodily resurrection of Jesus or the Trinity). Why do you believe these core tenets of Christian orthodoxy to be in jeopardy based on the scribal errors you discovered in the biblical manuscripts?"
Bart Ehrman: “Bruce Metzger is one of the great scholars of modern times, and I dedicated the book to him because he was both my inspiration for going into textual criticism and the person who trained me in the field. And even though we may disagree on important religious questions—he is a firmly committed Christian and I am not—we are in complete agreement on a number of very important historical and textual questions. If he and I were put in a room and asked to hammer out a consensus statement on what we think the original text of the New Testament probably looked like, there would be very few points of disagreement—maybe one or two dozen places out of many thousands.
The position I argue for in Misquoting Jesus does not actually stand at odds with Prof. Metzger’s position that the essential Christian beliefs are not affected by textual variants in the manuscript tradition of the New Testament. What he means by that (I think) is that even if one or two passages that are used to argue for a belief have different textual reading, there are still other passages that could be used to argue for the same belief. For the most part, I think that’s true.
But I was looking at the question from a different angle. My question is not about traditional Christian beliefs, but about how to interpret passages of the Bible. And my point is that if you change what the words say, then you change what the passage means. Most textual variants (Prof. Metzger and I agree on this) have no bearing at all on what a passage means. But there are other textual variants (we agree on this as well) that are crucial to the meaning of a passage. And the theology of entire books of the New Testament are sometimes affected by the meaning of individual passages.
From my point of view, the stakes are rather high: Does Luke’s Gospel teach a doctrine of atonement (that Christ’s death atones for sins)? Does John’s Gospel teach that Christ is the “unique God” himself? Is the doctrine of the Trinity ever explicitly stated in the New Testament? These and other key theological issues are at stake, depending on which textual variants you think are original and which you think are creations of early scribes who were modifying the text.”

Bart Ehrman, Misquoting Jesus (New York: HarperSanFrancisco, 2005), 252-3, Emphasis added.
FOURTHLY, we have two helps to help us identify which variants are true.  Where a variant is clearly contrary to the rest of God's Word, where it is a single variant with all other variants unified in the text, where it exists in a much larger work which is otherwise clearly doctrinally dubious: all these help.  The Holy Spirit guides the believer into all truth.  The textual critics that are Christian are also so guided.
FIFTHLY, there are only three passages in the NT that are suspicious enough to be highlighted (or even omitted) in modern versions,  John 7:53-8:11, Mark 16:9-20, and the different rendering of 1st John 5:7-8. None of these are critical for essential Christian doctrine.  The trinity in 1st John 5:7,8 can be found elsewhere.

"It is really not possible or useful to produce a Bible with all the variants. Most variants make no difference whatsoever to the English translation."  Of course I wouldn't want all those variants that don't make a difference in meaning.  My Q has to do with making sure the 3 text traditions are well represented in footnotes that could also include a judgment from within each tradition on how that variant is likely.  Each translation based on a text tradition already winnowed out meaningless variant BY THAT tradition, so in my ideal Bible those don't need to be mentioned at all.

I've got it... yes that would be useful.  Bart Ehrman's quote "maybe one or two dozen" variants would make a significant difference to the meaning of maybe even a whole letter - but his reference to the trinity and his question Does Luke's Gospel teach a doctrine of Atonement? -  though interesting to further examine, don't give us much confidence as to his spiritual judgement.

In my ideal Bible, let the reader decide and theologize for himself/herself.  I just want the 3 tradition text critic (TR, NA, and Septuagint) to do their job well within their text-tradition, and their work presented in a single Bible volume.  Also, you're not really answering my question here (so, sorry cannot give you a +1 yet), although I read through all your answer and find it useful.  Will watch the YouTube when I'm less busy.

The Septuagint is the OT not the NT.  But it would be useful to have a Septuagint OT alongside our English based (mainly) on the Masoretic Text.  Why not just have the KJV or NKJV sitting side by side with a modern version or two on your lap?  And, where a verse seems to be especially problematic, consult more versions on Biblehub.org?

Thanks, I meant the Eastern Orthodox text tradition that uses Septuagint for the OT.  I corrected my question accordingly.  Why not just have ... side by side.  It's for convenience.  Also, I want the text-critic's choice of variant in Greek to be in the footnote too, which NKJV/KJV doesn't have.  Maybe I have to develop a special web app for this myself.

You continue speaking of the TR as if that is one of the original Greek-text families.  It gets a bit more confusing: the TR was an amalgamation of different textual families... mainly, but not exclusively, from the Byzantine Text.  So do you want the variants for the TR as well as the Byzantine variants? Also, every publication of the NA comes out with amendments.  So, its all a bit tricky.  (The RSV offers alternate readings without getting overwhelming.)

I see your point.  Basically, I want variants held up highly by groups of Christians today so in a single volume I can see the best variants from 3 groups (KJV-only, most recent NA, and EO).  Or let's make it 4 to include RC.  That way, there is no group saying that this Bible is missing something (apart from their variant not being chosen to be the main text).

Try the Interlinear Greek-English New Testament put out by Zondervan

Featuring the interlinear text as a third translation, this interlinear Greek and English New Testament sets the New American Standard Bible side by side with the New International Version. It includes a Greek/English dictionary keyed to G/K numbers for easy accessibility to all users, as well as parsing and G/K numbers for each word.


Does the book points out consistently BOTH the critical and the textus-receptus Greek editions?  To qualify as an answer, you have to show that the book does that.

I'm not going to down-vote or flag or anything but may I just point out that this should be a comment, not an answer.

A picture or quote about how this edition fulfills the request would make this answer a good one.
