Why was the Byzantine text type written?
How could the writers of the Byzantine text type add to the text of the Bible with a pure heart?
I understand there are almost no New Testament Byzantine texts before the year 300 A.D.
The earliest Bible texts we have are the Alexandrian text type, each more minimalistic than the Byzantine.
Why did the writers of Byzantine (or rather the Editors) add text even though it wasn't inspired, unlike the original text? Wouldn't God have Protected the original text?

Why assume such malicious intent like that? Give someone a typical English Bible today, and they might not realise that the section headings, verse numbers, and footnotes are insertions and not original. Likewise all text types of the Greek NT have examples of insertions and deletions, where we can assume that mistakes were made or editorial remarks weren't recognised as editorials by later copiers. The Byzantine text type just has more than the other text types.

@curiousdannii Wouldnt God have Protected the original original text?? Like the additions werent inspired so why did they end up being canonized?

You need to read the standard textbook for Tc: The Text and Transmission of the NT by Metzger Ehrman, to know all about the interpolations to the text.

How do you know that it was the Byzantine text that added things and not the Alexandrian text that took them away? It is my understanding that entire books have been written in defense of some such passages such as 1 John 5:7-8, the last twelve verses of Mark, and John 7:53-8:11.

I would request some source for this claim, and minimal research effort here. While I am usually eager to jump and do the work for the person asking the question, with the rather malicious assumption I am disinclined this time, some evidence please.

@Wyrsa Im sorry, english isnt my mother tongue & it could be that it came out more uncouth than meant. Im in so many deep religious Information rabbit holes, which Im trying to claw out of that Im trying to do as minimal research as possible, otherwise Im going crazy. I dont have any source, I just thought by myself: hm the earliest manuscripts are alexandrian & the doubts stepped in & WHAT IF the byzantine text was all added and its not that we just didnt find any early byzantine manuscripts?? I seriously ask myself how the faithful copy scribes maybe added sth knowing of verses like

Rev 22,18. Is there a benevolent explanation for these theories?  With that being said Im  also not eagerly waiting to refute the Bible.

Ah, that helps with the clarification here. And yes I know what you mean about being in deep rabbit holes... I'm in a few on other subjects, religion I get to avoid that due to my faith. :) There is a benevolent explanation. I'll try to answer now that I understand. To be clear, it was not the english language that was the issue, it was mostly the concern that you had done "no effort" which is a little "impolite" on this website. So you have no source is a concern, but I think I can give you a broad answer regardless.

The reasons why the Byzantine Text arose is what I take to be the point of the question but this is a massive subject, so I can only make summary notes. Proofs are to be found in a scholarly article about this, from which I mention some of the problems that had to be overcome. References at the end.
The Apostolic Greek text started to be corrupted in many places by the superimposition of Coptic (i.e. Egyptian) spellings, grammatical structures, and word order upon the text. The Apostolic Greek text was re-edited to make it match the Coptic text. Critical work of some early Church Fathers (such as Origen and his followers) often critically amended the text according to their mystical/allegorical interpretations of scripture. Also, some heretics in Egypt did damage to the text in key places.
After the persecution of Christians during the 2nd and 3rd centuries, and especially after the 4th century Council of Nicea, began to revise their manuscript copies of faithful apograph copies that had come directly from the original autographs, and retained in apostolic churches in the Byzantine Empire (Asia Minor) and in Rome. This resulted in the appearance of the Byzantine text, which led to the universal rejection of the Egyptian text for 1,400 years.
This work to standardise the Greek text was vital to overcome the damaging effects of ten persecutions against Christians. Also, the influence of the Arian heresy (for about 40 years). It took Emperor Justinian crushing three Arian kingdoms (the Lombards, the Vandals and the Ostrogoths) in AD 544 to help counteract the Arian influence upon copies of the N.T. in Egypt. Justinian also ended the influence of Origen at the council of Constantinople in AD 543. It was well known that Origen had altered the Egyptian text. Thus, during the 5th century, the Byzantine text gained dominance, and the church began to shelve the Egyptian text. By the 9th century all remnants of the Alexandrian text essential died out apart from the Coptic church (and allies) who had been universally excommunicated in the 5th century for not complying with the Council of Chalcedon.
The article from which this summary information is selected maintains (and I quote) that “The Egyptian text cannot be the Providentially preserved text, because it was not preserved in all generations nor in the Church’s mouth in all ages.” Of course, where the Alexandrian and Western texts agree with the Byzantine text, those readings were preserved, but not the distinctive Alexandrian or Western readings.
In the 20th century, the so-called Byzantine majority texts of both Hodges & Farstad, and Pierpont and Robinson, were fatally flawed. Those editors admit that they relied in the main upon the work of Baron Hermann von Soden and his 1913 text. Herman Hoskier, who promoted the traditional text, gave proofs when reviewing von Soden’s text in the Journal of Theological Studies that Soden’s text was littered with errors.  However, that goes beyond the scope of this question. It just serves to show, however, what a raging battle there continues to be over the centuries as to which manuscript collections can be trusted. The Byzantine text is vitally important in that respect, but it has to be true to the initial Byzantine text.
A most scholarly examination of the whole matter, which led up to the publication of the New King James Version is detailed in The Trinitarian Bible Society Quarterly Record, Issue No. 581, October to December 2007. The TBS does not recommend the NKJV and gives many reasons why not.
This has 40 pages of explanations, plus 4 pages of Endnotes. Then there followed the next issue of the Quarterly Record, continuing this massive subject.  It is Issue No. 582, January to March 2008, with 43 pages critically examining the N.K.J.V., with 3 pages of Endnotes. Anyone wishing to thrash out the matter of the Byzantine text and the history of different collections of manuscripts could do no better than get hold of the Trinitarian Bible Society’s two issues.

The first thing required for this is some proper context, not just historical this time.

We are talking about Alexandrian vs Byzantine manuscripts. (Ignoring the dead sea scrolls) The first thing to be aware of is the climate. The argument about which set of "old documents" is still preserved today is highly affected by this. The alexandrian ones had the benefit of being in a more arid environment which would help preserve them.
Of the surviving copies of just those two "families" of manuscript. about 95% are Byzantine and 4% are Alexandrian. (with the other 1% being other sources)
The earliest date for Byzantine surviving manuscripts is 5th century vs the alexandrian 2nd. This does not mean that one text is more accurate though.
Also, as pointed out on the answer to this question here

No one manuscript source is considered perfectly reliable, so the UBS Greek text will not match any specific manuscript or family of manuscripts. -Peter Kirkpatrick

Regardless, here are some things to consider...

The first thing of interest that I'd like to address is your claim "to add text, even though it wasn't inspired"
This is of course a valid concern, however we should have some trust and faith in this matter.
For example, we might not have 2nd century manuscripts from the Byzantine set. We do see 2nd century church fathers quoting the byzantine readings of scriptures. I believe we should trust the Saints/Holy Spirit in this matter.
Another reason to consider the Byzantine texts as more valid is that the alexandrian ones were not spread as widely and were not referenced or copied as often. Similar to how in the scientific world, a paper is higher value and more respected and valued if it is cited, quoted, and reprinted. The church fathers, scribes, etc. did not recopy/reference the alexandrian texts. This implies that the early church and early christians considered the Byzantine version superior.
And while the texts were copied by humans, who do make mistakes. It is unlikely that every single copy was flawed. Texts were generally copied by multiple people, so each of them would have had to make the same error for an error to be preserved in all texts. This is why modern scholars compare texts to remove the small possibility of this type of error.
The most common "error" are similar to variation on the same meaning. "He said" vs "Jesus said" vs "He said to them" etc. None of those would be as critical as say "And the Word was God" vs "And the Word was a god" (a modern example)
It does seem that some things are missing from the alexandrian manuscripts, this could be a preservation issue. (Consider the Gospel according to Mark 16 where verse 9-20 is missing) This implies that the Byzantine texts are "more full" or "more complete"
And finally God preserved and kept the Byzantine texts known through the entire history of the Church. While the Alexandrian ones "disappeared" for over 1000 years before being rediscovered.

The words of the Lord are pure words, Like silver tried in a furnace of earth, Purified seven times.
You shall keep them, O Lord,
You shall preserve them from this generation forever. – Psalm 12:6-7

There is also Matthew 5:18 that implies the preservation of Scripture.

According to a Protestant expert from the Orthodox Presbyterian church "Dr James W. Scott" who I'm citing as a copy expert reference (and not a theological source.)

Over the years, my work has often involved checking authors' quotations from the Bible and other sources. I have carefully observed the nature of copying mistakes, and I can report that accidental omissions—even of whole clauses and sentences—are much more common than additions. My acquaintance with the actual copying process, then, leads me to think that the Alexandrian text is a corruption of the fuller Byzantine text, resulting from accidental omissions (and some deliberate editorial work).


Biased aspects/opinions below. I'm Eastern Orthodox. But this is part of my answer.
I believe that you do not need to be suspicious of either "family" of Bible translation. This is because you should also be guided by the Church and your priest. This basically prevents any concerns I personally could have, I could go with ANY bible to my priest and ask something. He would explain it to me, perhaps check the church Bible if I came with a strange translation.
I would be wary of Bibles that are only used by 1 particular denomination and not shared by other churches. NIV, NKJV, etc... are all used by multiple churches, this is a good sign. I will not point out a specific Bible translation that I mistrust, but there are translations that I reject.
The benevolent answer/theory you are asking about is simply that God would not allow the church to decay into heresy entirely. If the Byzantine texts were heretical and the Alexandrian texts were lost for 1000+ years, then the church would have been "lost" for a long period of time, which is unthinkable based on God and Jesus' promises.

Just revisited this question and your benevolent answer/theory. Nice.
